# What is the name of the glyph that looks like a dash, but tapers on a single end?

Tags: punctuation, symbols

What is the name of the symbol shown below used to sometimes stylize page numbering or to call attention to an item in the page? It's hard to explain with words, but here's a picture.

[image: dashes similar to em- or en-dash]

Does this have a name? It looks like a dash with a tapered end. I'm looking for the general name of this type of dash, the unicode code, or for information about the font family that it is tied to.

Comment: It is not a standard typographic symbol, more like a graphic design.

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/70930/what-is-the-name-of-the-glyph-that-looks-like-a-dash-but-tapers-on-a-single-end). This question should have been migrated, not asked again.

Answer (score 13):

These types of symbols are generally called ***ornaments*** or sometimes ***typographic ornaments*** (see [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/24814/what-do-they-call-those-scrolly-curvy-elements-next-to-chapter-titles) and the comment below for more info and alternate names).

Your example is specifically a ***page ornament***.

I would not call this a dash. If you want to use it, you should probably search through various ornament packs (some fonts even have their own sets of ornaments). You might also consider asking on the graphic design SE.

Comment: Also known as dingbats. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dingbat